# How to install dependencies from a copied pipfile inside a virtual environment?

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, pipenv

The problem originates when I start by cloning a git project that uses pipenv, so it has a Pipfile + Pipfile.lock. I want to use a virtual environment with the project so I run `pipenv shell`. I now have a virtual environment created and I am inside the virtual environment. The project obviously has a lot of dependencies (listed in the Pipfile). I don't want to have to go through the list in the Pipfile one by one and install them using `pipenv install <package_name>`. Is there a pipenv/pip command that installs all the packages from a Pipfile I already have? Or maybe I need to set up the environment differently than running `pipenv shell`?

Answer (score 112, accepted):

The proper answer to this question is that `pipenv install` or `pipenv install --dev` (if there are dev dependencies) should be ran.  That will install all the dependencies in the Pipfile.  Putting the dependencies into a requirements.txt and then using pip will work but is not really necessary.  The whole point of using pipenv for most people is to avoid the need to manage a requirements.txt or to use pip.

EDIT: if the virtualenv is already activated, you can also use `pipenv sync` or `pipenv sync --dev` for the same effect.

Comment: Hi I know this is old, but I have a pipenv virtual environment working well on one computer. I want to recreate that virual environment on another computer. So how do I go about doing this? Your answer is lacking a lot of detail. Previously I would just have a requirements.txt and just copy it over to the new virtual environment I want to setup on another computer. So which file do I copy over now? Do I copy over the Pipfile and Pipfile.lock ?

Comment: @ChumbiChubaGo You should be able to copy the Pipfile and Pipfile.lock, and `pipenv install` within the directory on the other computer. In the future, though, you should probably start a new question instead of bumping an old one.

Comment: `pipenv sync` worked best for me

Answer (score 29):

Ideally, you are encouraged to have a `requirements.txt` file which contains all the packages required for installation via pip. You can create this file by doing:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

You can convert a Pipfile and Pipfile.lock into a requirements.txt.

```
pipenv lock -r > requirements.txt
```

After that, you can install all your modules in your python virtual environment by doing the following:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Hopefully, I anwered your question.

Comment: @CalebSyring Also make sure to update the `requirements.txt` file by `pip freeze` file when you update/add new packages.

Comment: Okay, maybe this will reveal something wrong I'm doing, but pip freeze won't return anything. (I thought is was initially, but it was just some of the packages I had installed one by one before I asked this question) Have any ideas now that you know pip freeze doesn't return anything?

Comment: Can you check if a `requirements.txt` file is created in your working directory?

Comment: There is no requirements.txt in the working directory now. I am ABLE to create one by running your code, if that's what you are asking.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the conversion

Comment: Note that to install into the system's packages, you now do: `pipenv install --system`.  This is current as of July 2023.

Comment: pipenv lock -r doesn't work anymore

Answer (score 9):

use  `pipenv sync` to install all packages specified in Pipfile.lock.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue. For me, I exited the virtualenv and ran

```
pipenv --three sync
```

and it worked.

From what I can understand the idea is to create a new virtual environment using python 3 in my case. If you're using python 2 the above command would be edited to read

```
pipenv --two
```

The sync command copies all dependencies from the Pipfile.lock over to the new virtualenv.

Comment: Why did you run this? What does it do? Can you provide an explanation?

Comment: I've updated the answer to hopefully provide more detail

Answer (score 3):

**use pipenv sync in file Pipfiel**

---

this code refrsh lib in file type .lock

```
pipenv sync
```

use this run virtualenv Pipfile

```
pipenv shell
```

Answer (score 2):

if you are trying to install the dependencies from pipfile using pipenv then its simple, first start or create new virtual environment by running this in your project directory

`pipenv shell`

then to install dependencies from pipfiles run this in the directory where your pipfile is located

```
pipenv install
```